# Using as keyword and then length in the same ngIf

Tags: angular

I want to avoid multiple sync operations and would like to assign the async property with 'AS' keyword and further check the length.
I tried the following code, but it is giving error:

```
<div *ngIf="(selectedNames$ | async as selectedNames)?.length"> {{selectedNames}}</div>
```

I tried another option too and still it's the same:

```
<div *ngIf="((selectedNames$ | async) as selectedNames)?.length"> {{selectedNames}}</div>
```

Brackets do not seem to be at correct position. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the desired result is with two `*ngIf` directives. The first one, applied to an `ng-container`, defines the `selectedNames` variable. The second one applies the `*ngIf` condition, with `selectedNames.length`, to the `div` element:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(selectedNames$ | async) as selectedNames">
  <div *ngIf="selectedNames.length">
    {{selectedNames | json}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-binding-jprepz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.